# How to define ephemeralStorage using terraform in a aws_batch_job_definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I'm trying to define the [ephemeralStorage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html) in my aws_batch_job_definition using terraform, but is not working. I'm not sure where a I should put the parameter in the JSON neither in the GUI.

Here is my job definition:

```
resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "sample" {
  name = "sample_job_definition"
  type = "container"

  platform_capabilities = [
    "FARGATE",
  ]

  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "command": ["bash", "/root/plotter.sh"],
    "image": "995648859937.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/chia:latest",
    "fargatePlatformConfiguration": {
      "platformVersion": "LATEST"
    },
    "resourceRequirements": [
      {"type": "VCPU", "value": "4"},
      {"type": "MEMORY", "value": "15360"}
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "networkConfiguration": {
      "assignPublicIp" : "ENABLED"
    },
    "executionRoleArn": "${aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn}",
    "jobRoleArn": "${aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn}"
}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
}
```

Comment: You say it's not working, but your question shows no attempt to make it work. What have you tried that didn't work? Did you get an error or was the storage size simply not what you specified?

Comment: Ops, I should have been more clear. I tried to set `"ephemeralStorage": {"sizeInGiB": 200 },` in container properties and  in resourceRequirements but it didn't worked (the size of the disk still the default of 20GB)

Comment: Try setting the `platformVersion` explicitly to `1.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

We've also been struggling to find information on this and it [appears](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/npu485/can_increase_ephemeral_storage_for_fargate_jobs/) you can't.

The best workaround seems to be attaching and mounting an EFS volume, [e.g](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/efs-volumes.html#specify-efs-config):

```
{
  "containerProperties": [
    {
      "name": "container-using-efs",
      "image": "amazonlinux:2",
      "command": [
        "ls",
        "-la",
        "/mount/efs"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "myEfsVolume",
          "containerPath": "/mount/efs",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      ],
      "volumes": [
        {
          "name": "myEfsVolume",
          "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
            "fileSystemId": "fs-12345678",
            "rootDirectory": "/path/to/my/data",
            "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
            "transitEncryptionPort": integer,
            "authorizationConfig": {
              "accessPointId": "fsap-1234567890abcdef1",
              "iam": "ENABLED"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```